# Selected Radiobutton value is not getting posted to controller

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I am trying to have 2 radio buttons in my View for Permanent Address & Mailing Address. But the value of the selected radio button is not getting posted back to the Save method in the controller. Its null when it gets to the Controller’s Save method.I have the properties as 'Hidden', thinking it would get posted, but its not.

I tried 2 different ways to display the radio buttons –
a) by using one property “isPermanentAddress” for both radio buttons &
b) by using two different properties “PermanentAddress” & “MailingAddress”. But both didn’t work.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in Advance!

*My code:*

**View**:

```
<div>
   <span>@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsPermanentAddress, true) Permanent Address       
   </span>
    <br />
   <span> @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsPermanentAddress, false) Mailing Address  
   </span>
```

OR

```
<div>
   <span>@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.PermanentAddress, false) Permanent </span>
   <br />
   <span> @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.MailingAddress, false) Mailing </span>
 </div>

@Html.HiddenFor(model => model. IsPermanentAddress)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PermanentAddress)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.MailingAddress)
```

**Model**: Address

```
public bool? PermanentAddress { get; set; }

public bool? MailingAddress { get; set; }

public bool? IsPermanentAddress { get; set; }
```

**Controller**:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(Address address, bool? isPermanentAddress, bool? PermanentAddress, bool? MailingAddress)
{
   //code to process the data posted from the view.
}
```

This is how HTML looks in browser.

"True" for IsPermanentAddress is because i "true" in View. When i select Mailing, its still "False" in browser.

```html
<input id="IsPermanentAddress " name="IsPermanentAddress " type="radio" value="True"> " Permanent Address " <input id=" isPermanentAddress" name=" isPermanentAddress " type="radio" value="False"> " Mailing Address " OR <input id="PermanentAddress " name="PermanentAddress "
  type="radio" value="False"> " Permanent " <input id="MailingAddress " name=" MailingAddress " type="radio" value="False"> " Mailing "
```

Comment: Perhaps post how the HTML ends up looking in the browser?

Comment: @mplungjan: This is how HTML looks in browser. 
"True" for IsPermanentAddress is because i "true" in View. When i select Mailing, its still "False" in browser.

<input id="IsPermanentAddress " name="IsPermanentAddress " type="radio" value="True">
" Permanent Address "

<input id=" isPermanentAddress" name=" isPermanentAddress " type="radio" value="False">
" Mailing Address "

OR

<input id="PermanentAddress " name="PermanentAddress " type="radio" value="False">
" Permanent "


<input id="MailingAddress " name=" MailingAddress " type="radio" value="False">
" Mailing "

Comment: I added your comment as a snippet. It looks weird

Comment: @mplungjan: Thanks! yeah, that's what i was trying to figure out that why its looking weird. Didn't realize that i should have just added it in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the values of radio buttons with true.When the radion button is checked,the value true will be passed to action,or the value will not be passed.

```
<div>
   <span>@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsPermanentAddress, true) Permanent Address       
   </span>
    <br />
   <span> @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsPermanentAddress, true) Mailing Address  
   </span>
</div>
```